# Crack view in Database

Tags: database

I have database which have some views.

Im using DB VIsualizer tool to run queries and stuff ,now does anyknow how can I get the "Create" code of the View in the DB ,please>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in that specific tool, but assuming you're using MySql can use this query

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html

Comment: ta for that ..but im using msSQl db ... du know the command for that eh ?>

Comment: And the above command does not work in MySql? Have you tried? I don't know about MS-SQL, so, sorry.

Comment: above command should work on my-sql but yeah it turns out that there aint no command in MS SQL db ..shite l...thanks for help away :)